# Public variable of a class not maintaining it's value and not accessible in another class

Tags: c++, class, public

I have a project with `Class1` with a public function `tempfunc` defined as:

```
public:
int tempvar;
public:
int tempfunc(int temparg)
{
    if (temparg>0)
    {
        tempvar=temparg;
    }
    return tempvar;
}
```

Now in `Class1`, first I call `tempfunc` with `tempfunc(500)` and it sets `tempvar=500`. When, I try to use `tempvar` within the same `Class1`, its value is not 500.

Secondly, in another `Class2` which is called after `tempfunc` of `Class1` is called, I use the following code:

```
int tempvar2=Class1().tempfunc(0);
```

I expect the value of `tempvar2` to be 500 but its some dummy value.

What should I do to obtain the value of `tempvar` in `Class2` from `Class1` after `tempfunc` is executed.

Comment: Show us your code and then we'll tell you. :D

Comment: you should initialize your variables before using them.
Make sure in your constructor you are initializing your variables (even with 0 or null).

Comment: 1. **Post the code** 2. Judging from your example `Class2().temp`, I'd guess perhaps `temp` is a non-static member and you're accessing it on a different instance each time.

Comment: Voting to close: The question is equivalent to *I live somewhere out of some city, after a car passed by, without telling you the city, what is the weather like at my place?*

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry for no code initially :)

Comment: @omnetuser99 You've responded by posting partial code. Please post the FULL code, including every class, function call, and anything else relevant, rather than trying to describe it. For example, it's not at all clear what you mean by "Now in Class1, first I call tempfunc" - do you really mean you're calling it IN Class1 i.e. from another function inside the class? Or, when you say "in another Class2 which is called" - there is no concept of calling a class in C++. Full code please. However, from the limited code you've posted, it looks like sftrabbit's answer is appropriate.

Comment: @omnetuser99 See the edit on my answer.

Comment: @omnetuser99 Don't just edit my answer into your question. Now your question makes no sense. Start again. Post another question and do it properly this time. Show us your class, THE CODE THAT USES THE CLASS, and the output you're getting.

Comment: No actually it was there, I forgot to put it into the code, but it was already there and wasn't working with it :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to use my psychic powers and try to figure out what you're doing wrong. I guess (from something you said in your second question) you're doing something like this:

```
class Class1
{
 public:
  int temp;
  void tempfunc(int x) { temp = x; }
  void someOtherFunction() { std::cout << temp << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  Class1().tempfunc(5);
  Class1().someOtherFunction(); // Prints some garbage value, not 5
}
```

Now I'll explain why this doesn't work. A class is a description of what your objects of that class type will be like. The class itself doesn't have an `int` object (it's just a description), but an object of `Class1` type *will*.

Now, in the code I gave above, `Class1()` creates an object of type `Class1` but is unnamed and temporary, meaning it will be destroyed at the end of the line. We are calling `tempfunc(5)` on that temporary object, setting its `temp` member variable to 5. But then it's destroyed. In the next line we create *another* new `Class1` object and call `someOtherFunction` on it - but *this* object hasn't had it's `temp` member set to 5, it just has some arbitrary uninitialized variable (this answers your second question).

If you want to use the same object of type `Class1` for both functions, you'll need to do:

```
Class1 obj;
obj.tempfunc(5);
obj.someOtherFunction();
```

This creates an object of type `Class1` and names it `obj`. Then we can call the functions on that named object.

---

After your edit: You declare `tempfunc` as returning an `int` but do not return anything from it. You need:

```
int tempfunc(int temparg)
{
    if (temparg>0)
    {
        tempvar=temparg;
    }
    return tempvar;
}
```

Comment: With even the return `tempvar` it's not working. Secondly, I am calling `tempfunc(500)` through another function in `Class1`.

Comment: @omnetuser99 The question is closed. Start again. Post another question and do it properly this time. Show us your class, THE CODE THAT USES THE CLASS, and the output you're getting.